# Title: "Angular Js Data is not formatted properly"

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

When a user clicks through to their User Profile Page they are supposed to see friendly dates. Instead they see the raw Javascript date. I am using a service to transform the data. I think the problem is related to ng-click and href that is being used. I do this throughout my Single Page Appllication using the MEAN Stack and the only pages that have problems are the ones that use ng-click to open.

The link which navigates the user to their User Profile is the following

```
<a ng-show="authenticated" href="#/usrProfile" ng-click="showUser(current_user)">{{current_user}} </a>
```

Clicking on the above html link opens their User Profile page. The correct date time is there but it is not rendered properly. It shows, for example "2015-12-01T01:19:22.947Z", instead of "Nov 30, 2015" which is adjusted for their timezone and more human readable. If the user clicks the back button of the browser, then clicks the forward button it will show the same date properly rendered.

The date is rendered by Angular outside the controller using a service. The service renders the date with the following code

```
vUsrProfile.usrCreatedDate = $filter('date')(vOriginalUsrCreatedDate,"MMM d, y", $rootScope.current_offset);
```

The data in the service is passed to the controller using the following code

```
var usrSingle = usrTracker.getProperty();
$scope.usrSingle = usrSingle;
```

The code to display that date is this code

```
<h5 title="Date {{usrSingle.username}} joined">{{usrSingle.usrCreatedDate}}</h5>
```

I am missing something. It feels like the data is being displayed before the service has transformed it.

I hope this makes sense. It seems like a hard problem to describe.

MORE DETAILS:

Controller code. Passing data from one controller to another.

```
// Controller for link
app.controller('mainController', function ($scope, usrTracker, usrServiceById) {
// removed non-relevant code ...
    // get single user data
    $scope.showUser = function (vUsername) {
        usrTracker.setProperty(usrServiceById.get({ "username": vUsername }));
    };
// removed non-relevant code ...
});

// Controller User Profile Page
app.controller('usrPageController', function ($scope, usrTracker) {

    var usrSingle = usrTracker.getProperty();
    $scope.usrSingle = usrSingle;

// removed non-relevant code ...
});

// factory for a single user
app.factory('usrServiceById', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/usrProfile/:id', { id: '@_id' });
});

// factory to hold user data between controllers
app.factory('usrTracker', function ($filter,$q,$rootScope) { 
    var vUsrProfile = {
        username: 'username',
        usrEmail: 'usrEmail'
        , usrFirst: 'usrFirst'
        , usrLast: 'usrLast'
        , usrTimezone: 'usrTimezone'
        , usrGender: 'usrGender'
        , usrBirth: 'usrGender'
        , usrPrefHours: 'usrPrefHours'
        , usrSocAuth: 'usrSocAuth'
        , usrCreatedDate: 'usrCreatedDate'
        , usrAccessToken: 'usrAccessToken'
    , usrRefreshToken: 'refreshToken'
        , usrOffset: '+0000'
        , usrDesc: 'usrDesc'
        , userSocId: 'userSocId'
    };
    return {
        getProperty: function () {
            var vOriginalUsrCreatedDate = vUsrProfile.usrCreatedDate; 
            vUsrProfile.usrCreatedDate = $filter('date')(vOriginalUsrCreatedDate,"MMM d, y", $rootScope.current_offset);
            return vUsrProfile;
        },
        setProperty: function (value) {
            vUsrProfile = value;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Without seeing the code of the controller and of the service, we can't help. Why don't you use the date filter from the view directly, anyway? That's its intended usage.

Comment: My thought was I could catch any date and display it the same if I do it in the service. You are right it works if I transform the dates in the page. I will add the controller and service code.

Comment: It seems I misinterpreted your question? Right.

Comment: Yes. You gave the direct answer Gandalf, but I am doing things a little different. The code you gave works if I were filtering the date in AngularJS on the page but I am trying to do it in Javascript in my module file.

Comment: I have deleted my answer mate :) You can format the code when you are making entry to your respective database, add the values in the format you want them to be. But I will recommend the default system as it can be formulated into whatever format we want easily plus it makes searching and sorting very easy.

Comment: I almost forgot the main reason I did it this way. I am trying to transform the dates into the User's Home timezone. Not the timezone in their browser the but the timezone saved in their profile. I couldn't find a way to add the user's timezone into the Angular date filter. I could hard code one but it was hard to bring the timezone from the MongoDB into the AngularJS.

Comment: I'd normalize dates in the backend/middleware so all dates have a suitable format and timezone correction is already applied. Only then spit them out via REST and use the Angular view filter to format them.

Comment: Johannes that is not a bad idea but this mostly works. The problem I feel like I am having is that it doesn't display at first. Almost like the $watch > $apply > $digest doesn't see it or something. It comes through if I hit the back button then hit the forward button.